# Is there a proxy software for Win to perform header injection?

Tags: proxy

I want to modify the header of all HTTP requests going through a proxy to inject some attributes into the header. I'm not planing any virus/hack/fishing, I need to test a software who has to receive some user data (id, access control params) for each http request. I cannot log in to the system since the authentication/authorization mechanism cannot be used for test purposes.

So for any http request I want to intercept it at the proxy and add attributes to the header which will help me simulate a logged user with specific credentials.

Do I need to program a servlet myselft or does any one knows of something (like HAProxy, but for windows).

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**WebScarab**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) is great for this.  It's a Java app, runs anywhere.  Kind of painful to get SSL working right, but otherwise is fantastic.

Comment: Can it be automated? Or is only possible to intercept http and manually add something?

Comment: @code-gijoe By automated, do you mean inject variable attribute values in the header?  If so, then I'm not sure.  I've only used it to inject static headers.

Comment: I was looking for "Bean shell".

Comment: @code-gijoe Ah, gotcha.  I've only played with that very minimally.  Hope it's working well for you!